How to automate the ChatGPT website with new security updates?

ChatGPT used to be fairly easy to automate via an extension on the page (which is allowed according to what an openai customer rep told me via chat), you used to just call the backend API/conversation end point, as you can see above, with the same payload that it's being shown initially with a body describing the new message ID and parent message ID etc., and it worked. Several extensions on the chrome store did this.
Now they have a few extra steps, significantly:
fetch("https://chatgpt.com/backend-api/sentinel/chat-requirements", {
  "headers": {
    "accept": "*/*",
    "accept-language": "en-US,en;q=0.9",
    "authorization": "Bearer <removed for 
  .",
    "content-type": "application/json",
    "oai-device-id": "<removed for security>",
    "oai-language": "en-US",
    "sec-ch-ua": "\"Not-A.Brand\";v=\"99\", \"Chromium\";v=\"124\"",
    
  },
  "referrer": "https://chatgpt.com/c/<removed for security>",
  "referrerPolicy": "strict-origin-when-cross-origin",
  "body": "{\"p: <removed for security>\"}",
  "method": "POST",
  
});

Which submits as the body the parameter "p" which appears to be some kind of key that must have been gotten or derived somehow from a previous request, but I'm not sure what.
Which then returns an object with a list of a few different kinds of keys (too big to copy here), which appear to somehow be used in this next request:



There's several keys that are included as new headers which appear to be partially based on the earlier payload.
The problem is that I'm struggling to figure how how those tokens are derived from the earlier payload. It's somewhere in the minimized code on the page but it's too complicated to navigate and figure out on my own. Plus I think there are several other requests that it's getting information from but it's too hard to figure out exactly what is done to get those token values.
When I try making the request to conversation with new message IDs etc like I used to, even when copying in some new token values, I always get the error "unusual activity detected..."
Has anyone figured out how to do this with the updated security?

After looking extensively in the sources tab I was able to find the functions that get the necessary tokens and generate the header info. It may be possible to reduce it even more but for now this is simple enough, simple import the relevant asset module at "https://cdn.oaistatic.com/assets/i5bamk05qmvsi6c3.js" and use the functions to get the token info then generate the headers, it's all in the pre-defined functions.
Here's the completed function I wrote for it (works on the console at chatgpt.com or as an extension):
async function AwtsmoosGPTify({
    prompt = "Hi! Tell me about the Atzmut, but spell it Awtsmoos",
    parent_message_id,
    conversation_id,
    callback = null
}) {

    var session  =await getSession()

    var token = session.accessToken;
    var convo = await getConversation(conversation_id, token)
    if(!parent_message_id) parent_message_id = convo?.current_node;

    async function getConversation(conversation_id, token) {
        return (await (await fetch("https://chatgpt.com/backend-api/conversation/" + conversation_id, {
          "headers": {
            "accept": "*/*",
            "accept-language": "en-US,en;q=0.9",
            "authorization": "Bearer "+token,
            
          },
          "method": "GET"
        })).json())
    }
    
    async function getSession() {
        return (await (await fetch("https://chatgpt.com/api/auth/session")).json())
    }
    async function awtsmoosifyTokens() {
        g=await import("https://cdn.oaistatic.com/assets/i5bamk05qmvsi6c3.js")
        z = await g.bk() //chat requirements

        r =  await g.bi(z.turnstile.bx) //turnstyle token
        arkose = await g.bl.getEnforcementToken(z)
        p = await g.bm.getEnforcementToken(z) //p token

        //A = fo(e.chatReq, l ?? e.arkoseToken, e.turnstileToken, e.proofToken, null)

        return g.fX(z,arkose, r, p, null)
    }
    t = {
        "action": "next",
        "messages": [
            {
                "id": generateUID(),
                "author": {
                    "role": "user"
                },
                "content": {
                    "content_type": "text",
                    "parts": [
                        prompt
                    ]
                },
                "metadata": {
                    "serialization_metadata": {
                        "custom_symbol_offsets": []
                    }
                },
                "create_time": performance.now()
            }
        ],
        conversation_id,
        parent_message_id,
        "model": "auto",
        "timezone_offset_min": 300,
        "timezone": "America/New_York",
        "suggestions": [],
        "history_and_training_disabled": false,
        "conversation_mode": {
            "kind": "primary_assistant",
            "plugin_ids": null
        },
        "force_paragen": false,
        "force_paragen_model_slug": "",
        "force_rate_limit": false,
        "reset_rate_limits": false,
        "system_hints": [],
        "force_use_sse": true,
        "supported_encodings": [
            "v1"
        ],
        "conversation_origin": null,
        "client_contextual_info": {
            "is_dark_mode": false,
            "time_since_loaded": 121,
            "page_height": 625,
            "page_width": 406,
            "pixel_ratio": 1,
            "screen_height": 768,
            "screen_width": 1366
        },
        "paragen_stream_type_override": null,
        "paragen_cot_summary_display_override": "allow",
        "supports_buffering": true
    }


    function generateUID() {
        return 'xxxxxxxx-xxxx-4xxx-yxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx'.replace(/[xy]/g, function(c) {
            const r = Math.random() * 16 | 0;
            const v = c === 'x' ? r : (r & 0x3 | 0x8);
            return v.toString(16);
        });
    }
    await sendIt(await awtsmoosifyTokens(), t)

   
    async function sendIt(headers, body) {
        var g = await fetch("https://chatgpt.com/backend-api/conversation", {
          "headers": {
            "accept": "text/event-stream",
            "accept-language": "en-US,en;q=0.9",
            "authorization": "Bearer " + token,
            "content-type": "application/json",
            
            ...(headers)
          },
          body: JSON.stringify(t),
          "method": "POST",
          "mode": "cors",
          "credentials": "include"
        });
        await logStream(g)
    }

    async function logStream(response) {
       var hasCallback = typeof(callback) == "function"
       var myCallback =  hasCallback ? callback : () => {};
        // Check if the response is okay
        if (!response.ok) {
            console.error('Network response was not ok:', response.statusText);
            return;
        }

        const reader = response.body.getReader();
        const decoder = new TextDecoder("utf-8");
        let buffer = '';
        var curEvent = null;
        while (true) {
            const { done, value } = await reader.read();

            if (done) {
                console.log('Stream finished');
                break;
            }

            // Decode the current chunk and add to the buffer
            buffer += decoder.decode(value, { stream: true });

            // Split buffer into lines
            const lines = buffer.split('\n');

            // Process each line
            for (let line of lines) {
                line = line.trim(); // Remove whitespace

                // Check if the line starts with "event:" or "data:"
                if (line.startsWith('event:')) {
                    const event = line.substring(6).trim(); // Extract event type
                    curEvent = event;
                    
                } else if (line.startsWith('data:')) {
                    const data = line.substring(5).trim(); // Extract data
                    
                    
                    // Attempt to parse the data as JSON
                    try {
                        const jsonData = JSON.parse(data);
                        if(!hasCallback)
                            console.log('Parsed JSON Data:', jsonData);
                        myCallback?.({data:jsonData, event: curEvent})
                    } catch (e) {
                        if(!hasCallback)
                            console.warn('Data is not valid JSON:', data);
                        myCallback({dataNoJSON: data,  event: curEvent, error:e})
                    }
                }
            }

            // Clear the buffer if the last line was complete
            if (lines[lines.length - 1].trim() === '') {
                buffer = '';
            } else {
                // Retain incomplete line for next iteration
                buffer = lines[lines.length - 1];
            }
        }
    }

}

